# Disable export feature in openerp 6.1.1 for users

Tags: odoo

I am using OpenERP 6.1.1. I wish to disable import/export feature in the sidebar for some of my users.

I tried various things but unsuccessful.

Please suggest. Thanks.

Comment: You just need a solution or need a correct solution? Because the solution I found is to edit the base code.

Comment: Presently I do not have any solution so any workaround would be fine. But yes, modifying the base code should be the last resort.

Please suggest. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a correct solution and also I haven't tried. 
You have to edit the base code.
Goto *openerp > addons > web > static > src > js* there is a file called view.js
Now goto the line number 811, there you can see something like

```
this.add_section(_t('Other Options'), 'other');
    this.add_items('other', [
        {
            label: _t("Import"),
            callback: view.on_sidebar_import
        }, {
            label: _t("Export"),
            callback: view.on_sidebar_export
        }
```

try commenting this code in that file.
Note: This is not the correct solution and I will not prefer editing the base code.

Comment: it worked for me though i couldn't do it on user bases but still. Also this works on web client only, but its fine with me.  
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a group without access to the object **ir.exports**
Assign that group to the users you don't want to be able to export (Be sure those users don't belong to any other group that has access to that object)